# How to create caption of combobox at the same line?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Vaadin's [comboBoxes](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/ComboBox.html) were designed to show captions and items are line by line (*you can see them in [here](http://demo.vaadin.com/valo-theme/#!comboboxes)*). If I want to see them in a same line , what is the solution ?

Now I am trying to get as below ....

```
    HorizontalLayout hlMain = new HorizontalLayout();
    hlMain.addComponent(new Label("Gender:"));
    final ComboBox gender = new ComboBox("" , genderList);
    hlMain.addComponent(gender);
```

But I know above code is too ugly , So I am trying to use with CSS . I would like to know has there easy way to get it with Vaadin ? Any suggestions will be great help for me.

Comment: do you mean the caption left of the input element?

Comment: @cfrick yes sir ! It's really what I want.

Comment: well what have you tried so far?

Comment: @cfrick I used with CSS , try to set style of caption `div` to `display:none;`. But I don't want to use to add new style name .. if possible !

Comment: well then add what you have tried to the question so others can advice on other things.

Comment: @cfrick Now I have edited my question sir ! CSS is still trying. I am a noob in styling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are willing to dedicate a layout to this, use a `FormLayout`:

```
// run with: spring run vaadin.groovy
@Grapes([
@Grab('org.vaadin.spring:spring-boot-vaadin:0.0.5.RELEASE'),
@Grab('com.vaadin:vaadin-server:7.4.4'),
@Grab('com.vaadin:vaadin-client-compiled:7.4.4'),
@Grab('com.vaadin:vaadin-themes:7.4.4'),
])
import org.vaadin.spring.annotation.VaadinUI
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest
import com.vaadin.ui.*

@VaadinUI
class MyUI extends UI {
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        setContent(new FormLayout( // XXX
            new ComboBox("Gender:").with{ addItem("M"); addItem("F"); it }
        ))
    }
}
```

Your current code would work, if you would not put the empty caption on the ComboBox (it makes Vaadin think, that there is something to show and render an empty line, break, and then the combobox).  Yet FormLayout is the superior solution.

```
// run with: spring run vaadin.groovy
@Grapes([
@Grab('org.vaadin.spring:spring-boot-vaadin:0.0.5.RELEASE'),
@Grab('com.vaadin:vaadin-server:7.4.4'),
@Grab('com.vaadin:vaadin-client-compiled:7.4.4'),
@Grab('com.vaadin:vaadin-themes:7.4.4'),
])
import org.vaadin.spring.annotation.VaadinUI
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest
import com.vaadin.ui.*

@VaadinUI
class MyUI extends UI {
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        setContent(new HorizontalLayout(
            new Label("Gender"),
            new ComboBox().with{ addItem("M"); addItem("F"); it } // no label!
        ))
    }
}
```

Comment: @cuttcards you are right.  i changed the wording, since it not "most likely" given the result, but it actually is.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Vaadin FormLayout component wherever you required to put caption before input fields.

Example:

```
// A FormLayout used outside the context of a Form
FormLayout fl = new FormLayout();
// Make the FormLayout shrink to its contents 
fl.setSizeUndefined();

TextField tf = new TextField("A Field");
fl.addComponent(tf);

// Mark the first field as required
tf.setRequired(true);
tf.setRequiredError("The Field may not be empty.");

TextField tf2 = new TextField("Another Field");
fl.addComponent(tf2);
```